# What is changing my line breaks?

Tags: php, windows, shell, line-endings

I am trying to read some binary data from a command line tool with PHP on Windows. Initially the tool was *git show*, but I can reproduce the problem with *type* as well (to make sure there is no *Git autocrlf* happening).

I am not sure what is going on, but somewhere on the way the line endings seem to be converted. Observe...

On the command line:

```
# dir temp
18.01.2015  03:24             1.362 temp
```

In PHP:

```
$data = `type d:\\temp`;
echo strlen($data);                            // outputs "1302"
echo strlen(str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $data)); // outputs "1362"
echo strlen(file_get_contents('d:\\temp'));    // outputs "1362"
```

What is going on? How can I get the verbatim data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file_get_contents()` will get you the verbatim data, binary safe. Avoid OS-specific things like `type` you used.

Try using other methods instead of backticks, like `passthru` for example:

```
ob_start();
passthru("git command blah blah");
$var = ob_get_clean();
echo strlen($var);
```

Comment: There is no file. It's the output from *git show* that I want.

Comment: @AndreKR, you should have told this straight at the beginning. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is this:

```
ob_start();
passthru('type d:\\temp');
$data = ob_get_clean();
```